# Pytest, setup_method, and class-level mocks

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have a test that originally looked something like this:

```
@mock.patch('serial.Serial')
class TestApi:
  def test_something(self, mock_serial):
    # The Gadget class opens a serial port with serial.Serial()
    gadget = Gadget('dummy')
    mock_serial.assert_called_with('dummy')
```

That works just fine...but I'm going to need the same `gadget` object in every other test, so I wanted to move the object creation into a `setup_method` method, which pytest will call prior to each test.  E.g.:

```
@mock.patch('serial.Serial')
class TestApi:
  def setup_method(self):
    # The Gadget class opens a serial port with serial.Serial()
    self.gadget = Gadget('dummy')

  def test_something(self, mock_serial):
    mock_serial.assert_called_with('dummy')
```

It looks as if the mocks aren't in effect when `setup_method` is called, so the above will fail with:

```
E           serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port dummy: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dummy'
```

Is there any way to make use of the class-level mocks from within `setup_method`?

Comment: Do you need exactly `setup_method`? I believe you can create a fixture `gadget`.

Comment: Yeah, I was beginning to think that might be better. I'll look into that shortly. Thanks!